# Website starts on weird position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the weirdest problem that just came out of the blue.
Whenever I [go to my page](http://samformatica.site11.com/nieuwe/index.php). The site starts on a weird position and I have no idea why.
I first thought it was my Jquery code that I use to scroll to a certain section, but it still did the same when I disabled it.
 I looked at the code around that part and there's nothing in it that should cause it to do that.
I've been searching for an hour and I just can't find out why it happens and I am getting kinda desperate.
It seems like it happens after a millisecond, because I can see the correct position for a very short time when I load the page.

The code is quite long around that part, but mostly text, pasting it here would be too much I'd imagine so you can always look at the page source.

If anyone has a idea it would be greatly appreciated, because it feels like I wasted a lot of hours of my time on something that just does this.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: It looks like it's scrolling to give focus to the first `<input>` field in your Contact form. Try removing any `autofocus` stuff and see if that helps.

Comment: Yup, that helped, can't believe I read past that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A funny and interesting question.

The problem is `autofocus` parameter on your `<input id="naam" name="naam" type="text" placeholder="Uw naam" required="" autofocus="">`

Comment: I checked all the code except for that form, it would have been so obvious. Thanks a lot for your help!